# Updated query showing error

Tags: oracle

```
Update E set Status = 0
From  EmployeeTest E
INNER Join  SecurityTest S on S.SecurityID=E.EmployeeID and S.SecurityLevel<>'Admin'
INNER Join  LOGINTest    L on E.EmployeeID=L.LoginID and LastLogin < Add_Months(Cast(SysDate as date),25) and E.Status=1
```

I'm getting error of "SQL Command Not Properly Ended"

Answer (score 1):

Improved Answer:

```
UPDATE 
(select e.status  from EmployeeTest E
INNER Join  SecurityTest S on S.SecurityID=E.EmployeeID and S.SecurityLevel<>'Admin'
INNER Join  LOGINTest    L on E.EmployeeID=L.LoginID and LastLogin < Add_Months(Cast(SysDate as date),25) and E.Status=1
) t
SET t.status = 0
```

Comment: Only yo'll have to put t.Status

Answer (score 1):

You may do it with `EXISTS`. I have removed `CAST ( SYSDATE as DATE )` as `SYSDATE` is already of date type

```
UPDATE employeetest o 
SET    o.status = 0 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   employeetest E 
                      INNER JOIN securitytest S 
                              ON S.securityid = E.employeeid 
                                 AND S.securitylevel <> 'Admin' 
                      INNER JOIn logintest L 
                              ON E.employeeid = L.loginid 
                                 AND lastlogin < ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 25) 
                                 AND E.status = 1 
                                 AND employeeid = o.employeeid );
```